# How to get process id of sbt?

Tags: sbt

How can I get process id of an sbt run?

I tried the following but it did not give me anything:

```
SBT="$(sbt -java-home /shared/shelley/khashab2/java/jdk1.8.0_31 'project core' run)"&
echo "$SBT"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash, you can try `$!`. From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0021-1):

> ($!) Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background, whether executed as an asynchronous command or using the bg builtin (see Job Control Builtins).

Comment: hmm I am using the script inside `screen`. I think `$!` will return the PID of the screen window.

Comment: No, it will return the PID of sbt. You can check it with `bash -c 'echo $$;sleep 10s' &` instead of your sbt command, the `$$` variable will ask the sub-shell to print its own PID (what would be the PID of sbt).

Answer (score 0):

change your script like this:

```
sbt -java-home /shared/shelley/khashab2/java/jdk1.8.0_31 'project core' run&
SBT=$!
```